# Unable to get custom order attribute from magento v2 soap api

Tags: api, soap, sales-order

here is the problem.

I have added additional fee to my orders. When calling the magento api v1 i get the response including this additional fee (called handling_fee_amount). But when calling the magento api v2, i can not get it. All I get are the usual attributes (not including this one).
Here is the soap call:

```
$session = $client->login('ApiTest', 'test_key');
$result = $client->call($session, 'sales_order.info', '100015226');
```

Also, I have added my custom attribute to the wsdl.xml and wsi.xml files in my own module like this:

**wsdl.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns:typens="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
name="{{var wsdl.name}}" targetNamespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}">
<types>
    <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:Magento">
        <import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" schemaLocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
        <complexType name="salesOrderEntity">
           <all>
                <element name="handling_fee_amount" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
           </all>
        </complexType>
    </schema>
</types>
```

**wsi.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:typens="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}"
         xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
         xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
         xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
         xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
         name="{{var wsdl.name}}"
         targetNamespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}">
<wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}">
        <xsd:complexType name="salesOrderEntity">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="handling_fee_amount" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
            </xsd:sequence>
          </xsd:complexType>
     </xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

But no changes. 
I have logged the call to the **info** method in **Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Api** and **handling_fee_amount** is there, but somehow when it is returned it is lost.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: did you clear the cache?

Comment: hi, yes I did, magento cache, but not WSDL. See answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so the problem was with the caching. The code above is working fine, but I did not clear the WSDL cache. This cache is located in **/tmp/** folder on your linux machine (not magento). WSDL cached files are **/tmp/wsdl-***. I deleted all of them and it all worked.

Comment: Please mark this as accepted.